# How can I open this door latch with the knobs removed?

Tags: basement, doorknob, knobs

So my stupid roommates not only put tape in the door but also took the knob off. I closed it while doing laundry and they dont know where the knob is or pieces to open it. Can yall help[image]

Comment: That gap between the door and strike plate is quite large. Use a butter knife to release the latch.

Comment: I would use a screwdriver to push the latch towards the middle of the door, you may need to wobble the door as the tang could have pressure on it...

Comment: I will try both right now. I swear I never had this much trouble with a door

Comment: Please tell us if you get it open, and which method worked.

Comment: Don't put metal tools between the door and the latch. You'll just damage the woodwork, which would be a shame because it looks like nice vintage work from real wood. Just think about how a knob could work, where/how it could apply pressure by turning, and it'll be clear what you have to do

Comment: I am trying more methods now. I am going to try pulling it because it still wont budge.

Comment: Pushing it worked and using a putty knife near the tape to hold it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's a C-shaped piece in the hole through the bolt near the right (inner) end. Press one leg of that toward the edge of the door (the latch). Normally there's a formed sheet metal shaft with an opposing C shape going through there that rotates and does just that.

[image]

Comment: I had used a stainless steel putty knife to hold near the tape and push. Thank you so much. I removed the tape. The last time im unlocking that door for them.

Comment: I'd recommend removing that hardware, then. Replacement knobs are fairly cheap, and if you don't open it for them someone will do real damage.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't pry the latch tongue out of the striker plate (door frame) with a butter knife or a credit card, then you must somehow grasp that C-shaped piece and pull it toward the center of the door. Find a screwdriver, knife, or similar tool that is just a bit larger than the space between the arms of the C, insert and twist it to get a grip.

As even your roommates now know, tape is the wrong solution here. The proper procedure is to remove the mechanism entirely. Scrape off the remains of the tape and remove the two screws beneath. Insert almost any tool into the C and push the entire thing out of the door.

Comment: You don't need to pull it; there's no way the knob could do that. You need to push it. See isherwood's answer.

Comment: You're right that most bolts operate as you describe here, though. This is an odd duck.

Comment: Even though this answer is wrong for this OP, I'm'a leave it here for anyone who has the same problem but with the more ordinary kind of latch.