# How to open a lock without handle?(with pic)

Tags: lock

[image]

I don't know how to open this, detail is shown in pic.
Plz tell me if you have a clue, thank you in advance.

Comment: I understand I should slide the grey part to the left, but since there is no hole/slot I can find on the grey part as shown in the pic, I don't know how to do this. And also, none of the visible black parts is connected to the grey part. Thank you for your answers guys.

Answer (score 2):

Now I have solved the issue.
The mechanism is in a reserved direction. To open the door, I need to push towards the latchbolt direction instead of the hinge side. Guess my lock is bit of different from others.
Thank you guys for your helpful advice.

Comment: This guy https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/168029/how-can-i-open-this-door-latch-with-the-knobs-removed#comment285925_168029 had the same kind of latch.

Answer (score 1):

Use pliers or a screwdriver to operate the mechanism, once open then repair it before closing it again.

Answer (score 1):

Harry, slide a slotted screwdriver into that 1/2 circle opening and push towards the hinge side of the door and it should open, if it's not broken. If the opening was square you would slide the flat screwdriver into the opening and turn it. That will open it.

Comment: yeah, use a pointed tool to slide the gray part to the left.